# Git clone into a set and empty directory

Tags: git

I would like to clone a git repo with a `crm1` folder name into `/crm` **without** the repo's root `/crm1` directory name, only the files.

At the end:

- I do not want to have `crm/crm1/<repo files>`
- I want to have `crm/<repo files>`

How do I achieve this with inline git commands?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`git clone <repo_address> crm/` will clone the contents of the repo at `<repo_address>` into the `crm/` directory.

Comment: Although the repo may be called `crm1`, using `git clone <repo_address> crm/` will clone the contents of the `crm1` repo into the `crm` directory.

Comment: Think of it this way: repositories don't really have names, just *locations* in a file system or on a server.

Answer (score 0):

Git clone . 
Above command will clone the project to existing directory